# Bake SCSS variables into reusable single component files Vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I would like to create a `npm` repo containing a folder with Vue single file components from which I can import then easily:

`import { Button } from "@user/design-system"`

the problem I have is that the `Button.vue` contains variables coming from  a global `.scss` file that is handled by Webpack.

How can I bake the variables into each component when I build for the npm release?
So essentially I want a dev environment which I run by `npm run serve` and I want a `npm run build` which copies all components and bakes the `CSS variables` into it to have stand-alone components.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this variables in a dedicated file (for example `_variables.scss`), in your project where you want to import your component. Then you should make this variables accessible to all the components. I suggest you to use [`style-resouces-loader`](https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader), that will import your variable in every component. Vue ClI wrapper - [`vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader).

To export your UI library with already inlined CSS, you should build your UI library through [`vue-cli-service build`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library). And then you can import your builded component with builded `CSS` styles, which was built from `SCSS`.

Comment: thats the current setup, but how am I suppose to preprocess things when another project wants to import the files and not want to set up the preprocessor in their own project?

Comment: @supersize, you should build your UI library through [vue-cli-service build](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library). And then yo can import your builded component with builded `CSS` styles, which was built from `SCSS`.

Comment: @supersize, You are welcome. Then I will edit the answer.